# OnTouch MotionEvent отрабатывается только первый раз

Tags: android

То-есть при первом нажатии мелодия играет при отпускании останавливается. Следующий раз уже ничего не происходит.

```
final ImageButton cow = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.cow);

cow.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int eventAction = event.getAction();
        if (eventAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            stopSound(catSound);
        }
        if (eventAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            playSound(catSound);
        }

        return true;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int eventAction = event.getAction();
         if (eventAction== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             stopSound(catSound);
return true;

} 
       if (eventAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
           playSound(catSound);                    
          }

              return false;

      }   
          });
```